# How to view design of JSP In eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-wtp

I have configured a J2EE project into Eclipse. The source code is consisting of JSP as well as Java Files.

Is there any way so that we can view the design of the JSP?

I am using Eclipse 3.1.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

goto window - preferences - general - editors - file associations

choose *.jsp

and in associated editors choose "web page editor" as the first default

Comment: Thanks for this one. Works fine for my project.

Answer (score 13):

You right click on the jsp file and then highlight "Open With" .You will get options like JSP Editor, Text editor, Web Page Editor. Please Select "Web Page Editor" option.

Answer (score 2):

Right click to the empty area in code page > go to Open With section > select WindowBuilder Editor. 
The Design Page will appear left-down. I solve it on Eclipse Neon.