# How to enable Design View in jsp file in Web application project in Netbeans?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, netbeans, web-applications

I'm working on a Web application project and I've added a jsp file but I can't see the Design View.

I don't know if this feature has been removed in new versions, but here here's a pic of Design View in a jsp:

[image: Image:]

How do I enable it?

thanks.

Comment: I don't think that there exists any such native Netbeans option to achieve this! You might be able to achieve this using an extra jar,if there exists one. Also, you can easily achieve this using softwares like DreamWeaver? May be I am not aware of this thing in NetBeans.......

Comment: Real programmers don't drag'n'drop code. Real programmers want full control over code so that code quality can be assured. Visual editors namely don't produce quality code.

Comment: Technically your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631130/where-is-visual-javaserver-faces-on-netbeans Do note that the article where you found the screenshot is 10+ years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `design view` was lastly available in Netbeans `version 6.7.1`. But in later versions it was unavailable. Yes to edit jsp you can use pellets and drag & drop HTML components. You can search for plugins but I don't think there is one for jsp. See this [message](https://netbeans.org/projects/www/lists/netcat/archive/2010-03/message/424).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from NetBeans 6.8, the Visual Web module is no longer available. refer link http://wiki.netbeans.org/VisualWebSupport

Answer (score -1):

This might help you. Here is the link ::  [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/visualwebdev/)

For eclipse refer this post : [Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255341/how-to-view-design-of-jsp-in-eclipse)